# Angular CDK table: Element 'td' cannot be nested inside element 'table'

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use the Angular CDK table in an Angular 7 project in Visual Studio 2017. When I follow the official code sample from [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview) it works perfectly but I get these warnings from visual studio: **Element 'td'/'th' cannot be nested inside element 'table'**.

Below is the code for reference:

```
    <table cdk-table [dataSource]="masterIds">

      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
        <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let id"> {{ ws[id].Name }} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="code">
        <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Code </th>
        <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let id"> {{ ws[id].Code }} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <tr class="small" cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['name', 'code']"></tr>
      <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let id; columns: ['name', 'code']" [routerLink]="['./', id]"></tr>

    </table>
```

Any idea how to get rid of these warnings? They are poking me in the eye. Thanks

**UPDATE**
Here is a picture of the warnings:

[image]

And the green squiggles :
[image]

Comment: You cannot have the <th> element outside of a <tr>.

Comment: @FatemeFazli Of course not, but this is the syntax for creating an Angular cdk table (As per the official docs), and Angular will compile this into a nice well formed table where every <th> is inside a <tr>. But during development visual studio is complaining and I wish to make it not complain

Answer (score 4):

I just found a way which "seems" to work; wrap all the column definitions inside an invisible `<tr>` element and that's that:

```
<table cdk-table [dataSource]="masterIds">

  <tr style="display:none!important">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
      <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let id"> {{ ws[id].Name }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="code">
      <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Code </th>
      <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let id"> {{ ws[id].Code }} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>


  <tr class="small" cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['name', 'code']"></tr>
  <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let id; columns: ['name', 'code']" [routerLink]="['./', id]"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this seems the only acceptable answer. Supressing warnings is not the way to go because it will stop to show other places on where is legit and useful to fix the problem. In other hand, the documentation must show instructions without this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

A `th` should be inside a `tr`, you should have something like :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### For your updated question

That's because of the Visual studio compiler itself, you can search for `How to suppress VS studio compiler warnings` (**[try this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2017#suppressing-warnings-for-visual-basic)**), **and a tip:** switch to `VsCode` for your frontend dev.

Comment: See the example in the official docs https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview#writing-your-table-template. Angular will eventually compile this into a proper table, but Visual Studio still shows warnings, how do I suppress those warnings.

Comment: @AAkra Tslint's warning ? could you attach an image for them ?

Comment: I updated the question with pictures, these are VS warnings, not tslint

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @AAkra [see this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2017#suppressing-warnings-for-visual-basic), and I advise u to switch to VSCode for your frontend dev, you do not need such an IDE for angulars' apps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although it doesn't say much about HTML warnings. The reason I use VS is because I'm building an ASP.NET Core back-end, and I'm using Visual Studio's Angular template. But I guess I could still use VS Code for the angular folder and VS for the rest of the project, if there is no way to suppress these warnings (which I would find hard to believe)

Comment: @AAkra yup, you can do so, better than getting a headache ;), welcome !

Comment: Switching to VS Code to avoid to see legit warnings seems wrong. Also, if you're working with front and back, in a project, doesn't have sense to use two IDEs when you can have one.

Comment: @zameb VsCode is not an IDE.

worked on front/back end and used to have both Intellij + VsCode opened